# How to read uptill a particular character in a file, without going through the file, character by character?

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

Want to detect the '\n' without going through each and every character of a text file. Any hints?

Comment: @BurnAfterReading http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Uptill

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thanks

Comment: Why do you want to detect the '\n' character. Sounds like you are trying to do something that is already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Something* has to read all the bytes to check for that delimiter.

Use one of the [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) (or [istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/)) functions so that the library does the searching, not your code.

Answer (score 3):

How about `getline(...)` from Iostream?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/